# Drop sniffed packet on matching content

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, networking

I have made a packet sniffer in C using rawsockets that sniffs all outgoing UDP traffic on a specified port.

I now want to drop certain outgoing UDP packets that match a certain payload, so that they can be resent with a different payload.

A sniffer will no longer be useful in this situation, because it seems unable to motify the network traffic it detects.

Is there a way to drop packets that match a certain payload and port on a Linux system *without* modifying kernel code? Is my sniffer useless for the goal I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant 1: create a `TAP` interface (if original interface is a kind of Ethernet or analog) and move network addresses to it. Packets arrived to physical interface are analyzed and then, if allowed to pass, sent to process side of this TAP interface. And, vice versa, packets sent by network stack to TAP interface are got by program and injected to the physical interface.

Variant 2: use `NFQUEUE` target of `iptables` subsystem. All packets which satisfy a rule condition are passed to userland analyzer for inspection and, if allowed to pass, for re-injection. This is better in sense that only needed subset of all packets can be directed to your filter.

Comment: Using `NFQUEUE` in `iptables` seems like the most elegant solution. Exactly what I was looking for. [Here's a useful sample](https://code.google.com/p/nattt/wiki/libnetfilter_queue_samplecode).